# hand Onclick event that is in the parent component react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I have a component that will return,

```
<div className="top-margin">
    {this.orgs().map( (o)=>{
        return <AOD obj={o} />
    })}
</div>
<div className="modal fade" id="add-modal" role="dialog">
    <div className="modal-dialog">
        <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" onClick={createOrg} className="btn btn-primary">Add new Project</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

The createOrg is in the AOD file. How can I call createOrg function from the AOD?

Comment: you mean to call onClick ?

Comment: This function should be in component which render method you paste here, I think. If it will be in AOD then firing it will affect every AOD component you have, and - as it's name suggest - it should add new org to org collection.

Comment: How can I do it? the function contains this.props.id. If I call it in the component I paste here, I cant get the id of the org. Sorry it is CreateProj.

Comment: can you post the createOrg function? If you pass down the function to AOD you can bind the function to the current component so that when the function is executed it will still use this same component's `this` thus having `this.props.id`

Comment: Thanks but this is solved.